# Boot stuck on HP logo after initramfs fsck

Tags: boot, grub-efi, initramfs, fsck

**Update:** I bit the bullet and did a fresh install, so this is no longer an issue. I don't think I'd consider it "solved" though.

Went to fire up my computer this morning and was met with the BusyBox initramfs prompt. After running `fsck` on both sda1 (my HDD) and sdb2 (my SSD with Ubuntu installation) my *HP Pavillion* went straight into booting, but gets stuck on the HP logo on black screen.

Things I've tried:

- Adding nomodeset to GRUB
- Examing BIOS boot order settings, but I couldn't find anything to change. When I power on my machine it has me select what to boot, and when selecting Ubuntu (the default) it gets stuck.
- I have a working bootable USB ubuntu on which I have been able to mount both drives. I tried reinstalling GRUB from there following instructions from [repair restore reinstall grub 2 with Ubuntu live CD](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).
- I'm sure I'm missing other things I've tried, I've been working on this all morning and would just like to get my computer to work.
- I see the EFI System on `sdb1`, although it says "not mounted".

Output from `lsblk` is:

```
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
loop0    7:0     0      2G  1 loop /rofs .... 
sda      8:0     0  931.5G  0 disk 
 └─sda1  8:1     0  931.5G  0 part  
sdb      8:16    0  119.2G  0 disk  
├─sdb1   8:17    0    512M  0 part  
├─sdb2   8:18    0  102.9G  0 part /mnt 
└─sdb3   8:19    0   15.9G  0 part [SWAP] 
sdc      8:32    1   29.9G  0 disk  
└─sdc1   8:33    1   29.9G  0 part /cdrom
```

I mounted it with

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi
```

and got

```
sudo chroot /mnt 
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sdb 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.  
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

from the grub installer.

After updating grub I'm still getting the same issue with getting stuck during boot.

Comment: "*I tried reinstalling GRUB from there but tells me it's missing EFI*" - you should edit your question with exact details. Explain exactly what steps you took and then provide the entire error verbatim. A common cause of file system corruption is a failing hard drive. Consider that the problem is a failing hard drive.  You may need to reinstall the OS depending on what parts of the file system were corrupted.  It would be a good idea to make sure your backups are in order in case the disk problems get worse

Comment: Thanks @Nmath, I edited my post to include clearer details about the grub install. I was hoping to not have to do a fresh install which is why I made a post, but I accept that it may come to that...

Comment: In the live session, when you open the "Disks" application, do you still have an EFI partition?

Comment: The question has been updated with the info formerly above.

Comment: Hi @kwins. di you try to boot older kernels as weil ?

Comment: Hi @jpbrain. I have not, I don't really know what this means/how to do it

Comment: @kwins. on the grub menu choose "advanced options for ubuntu" then select an older kernel to boot (let me know what options do you have).

Comment: @jpbrain Thanks. I have: Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-81-generic, that with recovery mode, and 5.4.0-80-generic both with and without recovery mode. Just tried 5.4.0-80 and it looks like I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: is secure boot disabled on bios?

Comment: Yes, secure boot is disabled